# XAML UWP progressring not acive when added to exisitng stackpanel

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I try to create a progressring in the existing stackpanel as follows

```
<ListView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="150" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemsPanel>

                <ListView.ItemTemplate >
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Height="150" Width="192" >
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Height="108" Width="192" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                <ProgressRing IsActive="{Binding IsActive}" Height="15" Width="15" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" TextAlignment="Center" Height="22" Width="192" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Assets/GothamLight.ttf#GothamLight"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

I have a observable collection of items as follows

```
public class MyListItem
{
    public int index { get; set; }
    public BitmapImage Image { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Duration { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
 private ObservableCollection<MyListItem> _yourCollection = new ObservableCollection<MyListItem>();
    public ObservableCollection<MyListItem> YourCollection
    {
        get { return _yourCollection; }
        set { _yourCollection = value; }
    }
```

I populate Yourcollection items as follows

```
for (int i = 0; i < noofimage; i++)
        {
                YourCollection.Add(new MyListItem { index = i, Duration = JSONscript.playlist.Contents[i].Duration, Name = JSONscript.playlist.Contents[i].Name, Description = JSONscript.playlist.Contents[i].Description, Image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(Imagepath[i], UriKind.Absolute)), IsActive = false });
        }
```

I try to set the IsActive of progressring as follows, but it doesnt work

```
if (YourCollection[videoindex].IsActive)
            YourCollection[videoindex].IsActive = false;
        else
            YourCollection[0].IsActive = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

[Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx) `INotifyPropertyChanged` to your model class `MyListItem`

The UI will get an event when you add or remove items from the collection but not if a single object itself changes.. therefore use the interface above